# Efficiently adding a new section in an ELF file

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, elf

I want to add a new section to an ELF file (say *E*) which stores the integrity hash of *.text* section. Assume I chunk the *.text* section into *T1,T2..Tn* and get the hash *H1,H2..Hn* and add all hashes to the *E* in a new *.my_hash* section.

One naive way to do this would be to

- Scan file *E* and compute/store the hashes in a separate binary file *B*
- Convert *B* to *B.o* file
- Do *objcopy --rename_section* to rename *.data* section to *.my_hash* section
- Finally merge *E.o* (which assume I also have before generating *E*) and  *B.o*

Any better way to do this?

Comment: Curious... what are you trying to accomplish by authenticating an individual section?

Comment: I am trying some changes in kernel source (interpreter) where I will be checking those tags.

Comment: It seems like you would want to sign the whole file, not just sections, since it would be trivial to e.g. modify critical parts of the `.data` section, or even change the entry point to go to your own stub.

Answer (score 4):

Use `objcopy --add-section`.  You may want `--set-section-flags` as well.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: The docs are ok on this: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/binutils/objcopy.html#objcopy.  But basically you can use `objcopy --add-section .my_hash=file`, and the contents of the file will be used verbatim as the section contents.

Comment: There is a difference between my approach and yours. Mine replaces '.data' which is loadable segment. But when we add a new section it cannot be made as loadable. Setting flags to 'load' gives a warning: allocated section `.my_hash' not in segment. Which means I cannot access '.my_hash' say via kernel to check integrity.